# installing terraform on CentOS

Tags: centos, terraform

How do I get my terrfaform installation working on centos properly?

The only way for me to run terraform commands is if I add the path to the terraform executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this Installation steps of Terraform for CentOS/RHEL.

Install `yum-config-manager` to manage your repositories.

```
$ sudo yum install -y yum-utils
```

Use `yum-config-manager` to add the official HashiCorp Linux repository.

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/RHEL/hashicorp.repo
```

Install.

```
$ sudo yum -y install terraform
```

For complete reference you can follow this [Install Terraform documentation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/install-cli).